# Encoding H.264 video using OpenH264

Tags: c++, video, encode, h.264, openh264

I'm currently trying to figure out how to encode video using OpenH264, but I just can't figure out what to put into the `SSourcePicture` structure. What does the `iStride` field represent? What does the `pData` field represent? How do I actually get the encoded data back from the EncodeFrame function? If I set the `iColorFormat` field to `videoFormatBGRA` would I be able to provide frames in BGRA format, or do I have to convert frames to YUV?